# step into web service on another LAN server

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm debugging a vb.net windows program which I've upgraded to a VS 2010 solution, targeting Framework 2. I need to step into a webservice's code. The web service is framework 3.5, also vb.net, running on a windows 2003 server on our LAN. I've seen a ton of crap on the Net about it, mostly other people who couldn't get it working either.

The error I get in VS2010 is the exact same one I got before upgrading the project from VS 2005:

---

Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server
machine [servername] failed. The Microsoft Visual Studio
Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be
running on the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance.

---

So I did what Help said to do and ran the VS 2008 remote debugging wizard on the host server. I have verified that the remote debugger is running as a service on that machine. And it still fails.

Little help? THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes here looking for this answer, here it is. No goofy 'Attach to Process', no weird bad instructions 
from websites going off on a million stupid tangents. This answer has been FALKENIZED.

When on the same LAN and on the same domain, remote debugging from Visual Studio 2010 works when you do the following steps.

1. on web service host machine, share the web application folder where the web service lives; give yourself 755 permissions.
   oops, give yourself wrxr permissions.
2. on local development machine, map a network drive to the [web service host machine][web app] folder you just shared.
3. copy the Visual Studio 2010 remote debugger folder (containing msvsmon.exe + support files) to web service host machine.
   Make sure you get the correct platform for your host server, e.g. x86, x64, etc. Remote debugger is found here:
   C:\Program Files\Visual Studio 2010\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger[platform]
4. on web service host machine, drag a shortcut from the newly-copied debugger to the desktop, then start the remote debugger
5. on local development machine, step thru code. when reaching a call to the web service, you'll be prompted to navigate 
   to the location of requested web service code file, which will then be available in your mapped path. Do it.
6. Finally after 1000000 headaches, you may start debugging your web service. CONGRATULATIONS